# How to add and show some attributes to a many2many relationship (OpenERP7)?

Tags: python, many-to-many, odoo, openerp-7

This is a tricky question.

I am trying to add some fields to a many2many table. I was googling and I found that I have to create an intermediate table to stores those fields. But it is not working very well.

My example:
I created a table (**training_course**). A partner can join to many **training_course**, and a **training_course** is made up by many partners (So, this is a **many2many** relationship). I have to store the date when the partner joined the course.

So, in the partner form, I have to see the list of the courses he has joined, everyone with their dates.

My code is:

**res_partner_course_rel** (This is the intermediate class generated by me -with name = **'res.partner.course.rel'**-)

```
 _columns = {
        'partner_id': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Partner', ondelete='cascade'),
        'course_id': fields.many2one('training.course', 'Course', ondelete='cascade'),
        'date': fields.date('Joining date'),
    }
```

**res_partner**

```
 _columns = {
        'courses': fields.many2many('res.partner.course.rel', id1='partner_id', id2='partner_course_rel_id', string='Courses'),
    }
```

The problems I have are:

- In the partners form, when I click on add a new record in the
  resultant list, I had to select the partner (which is a nosense,
  because it must be the current one).
- The resultant list only shows a column (**partner**), when I would
  like to show two (**course** and **date**).

Anyone can help me a bit, please? I am trying several things but I cannot manage what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If one course can have multiple dates (and not only one) then you define 3 tables (forget a many2many relationship):

**partner_course_rel (.py)** (you had this ok)

```
_columns = {
    'partner_id': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Partner', ondelete='cascade'),
    'course_id': fields.many2one('training.course', 'Course', ondelete='cascade'),
    'date': fields.date('Joining date'),
}

_sql_constraints = [
    ('rel_unique', 'unique(partner_id, course_id, date)', 'This course already give to this company!!'),
]
```

**training_course (.py)**

```
_columns = {
    'name': fields.char('Name'),
    'partner_rel_ids': fields.one2many('partner_course_rel', 'course_id'),
}
```

**res_partner (.py)**

```
_columns = {
    'course_rel_ids': fields.one2many('partner_course_rel', 'partner_id'),
}
```

And in the views:

**training_course (.xml)**

```
<field name="partner_rel_ids" nolabel="1">
    <tree string="Partners" editable="bottom">
        <field name="date"/>
        <field name="partner_id"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

**res_partner (.xml)**

```
<field name="course_rel_ids" nolabel="1">
    <tree string="Courses" editable="bottom">
        <field name="date"/>
        <field name="course_id"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

I think this solve your problem (IF ONE COURSE CAN HAVE MULTIPLE DATES).

Answer (score 3):

Delete the model ***res.partner.course.rel*** and create the model ***res.partner.course***. In this model will go all the information about the course.

**res_partner_course (.py)**

```
_columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Name', size=128, required=True),
        'date': fields.date('Joining date'),
        etc...
}
```

The table ***res.partner.course.rel*** will be created automatically when you do this (always with only two id fields) :

**res_partner (.py)**

```
_columns = {
        'courses_ids': fields.many2many('res.partner.course', 'res.partner.course.rel', 'partner_id', 'course_id', 'Courses', ondelete="cascade", help="Courses associated with the partner'),
}
```

To show this relation in the form of the partner you could do this:

**res_partner (.xml)**

```
<field name="courses_ids" nolabel="1">
    <tree string="Courses" editable="bottom">
        <field name="name"/>
        <field name="date"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

or more simple:

```
<field name="courses_ids" nolabel="1"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I apply your answer, the column date will be in the course table, and that is not a property from courses, that is a property from the relationship between partners and courses.

Comment: Notice that date is a property from the relationship because **SELECT C.id, R.partner_id, C.date FROM res_partner_course C, res_partner_course_rel R WHERE C.id = R.course_id** With this query  you have the course, the partner and the date of the relationship.

Comment: you were right! I tried and it is almost what I want. The problem is with the XML, let's continue with your example: I used your tag <tree>, but I am only seeing the column "name" in the tree. The rest of the properties do not appear.